# If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $f'$ is never zero but not necessarily continuous, is $f$ monotone?

Tags: real-analysis

If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$, and $f'$ is never zero on $(a,b)$, is $f$ monotone?

We can show that $f'$ is either positive or negative on the interval $(a,b)$, because it still satisfies the intermediate property even if it's not continuous at all points. But is $f'>0$ enough to guarantee that $f$ is monotone if $f'$ is not continuous at all points in $(a,b)$?

Comment: Why does $f'$ have the intermediate value property? If $f'$ is discontinuous, then at some point it can "jump" from positive to negative. But, you have assumed that $f'$ is never zero. So, it cannot have the intermediate value property.

Comment: doesn't darboux theorem claim that if f'(a)>0 and f'(b)<0, then the derivative takes every single value between a and b and this applied even if the derivative may not be continuous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The derivative of a function has the intermediate value property.
See [Darbouux](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20Darboux%27s%20theorem%20is,interval%20is%20also%20an%20interval.)
. Thus in your case $f'$ is always positive or always negative.  Now you can use the mean value theorem: $f(y)-f(x)=f'(\xi)(y-x)$ if $x<y$ with some $x<\xi<y$,

Comment: So you're saying the statement is true? I read somewhere that we needed continuity of f' to show monotonicity. I don't know why we would because the reasoning here makes perfect sense. That might have been a different theorem though

Comment: Visit the link in my answer. It says that the derivative of a function has the intermediate value property  in any case. I.e., also in the case when $f'$ is discontinuous.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Darboux. If $f$ is not monotonic, then $f$ is not injective (since it is continuous). So there exists $x < y$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$, and by Rolle's theorem, you deduce that $f'$ vanishes somewhere.

*Remark:* I say that you don't need Darboux, but this argument can also be used as a two-lign argument to prove Darboux.